# Bit packing blocks in Simulink?

Tags: block, bit, simulink, packing

Could anyone please explain to me what the bit packing blocks in Simulink do? I am currently learning programming, Simulink and control theory so I am not very proficient. I tried using the help windows in MATLAB and also googling but I haven't found anything that explains it well.

Based on the online researching, bit packing is used to condense data packets before they are sent to another block? This way, the program runs faster?

Also, in Simulink, what is the "Bit patterns:" box used for? For example, if I type {[0:7]} what would that mean?

Edit: Where should I go to learn more about this? Are there any good documents online?

Answer (score 0):

Byte packing and unpacking is used mostly for communications between a xPC Target and another device, over Ethernet for example.  If bytes are coming in, they can be condensed into other data types such as singles or doubles.  Conversely, if you are sending out doubles or singles, often you need to separate them into bytes first.